# XML report using SQL query

Tags: sql, xml, plsqldeveloper

I've 6 different tables. I need to create one XML report using these 6 tables in oracle with sql query. In that XML report data values are coming from 6 different tables.Moreover I don't find any relationship between these tables. Suppose if I find relationship what would be my approach to solve this kind of problem.

Please waiting for your valuable comments.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which language you are using to extract data into xml, Please provide full detail for effective answers.

Comment: share your 6 sample table and expected output ,otherwise no one can get what need for you

Comment: I can't provide tables name or sample data . It's like customer , policy details etc. I have to use SQL to generate XMl report.

Answer (score 0):

Start here.  This is the XMLGEN function.
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_xmlgen.htm#ARPLS374